# How to get unbounded classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to "wrap" an existing classmethod, i.e.,

```py
def Foo:
  @classmethod
  def bar(cls, x): return x + 2

old_bar = Foo.bar

def wrapped_bar(cls, x):
  result = old_bar(cls, x) # Results in an error
  return result

Foo.bar = wrapped_bar
```

It seems that `Foo.bar` is already bound with `cls = Foo`, how do I get the unbound version of the function `bar`?

[I'm not allowed to modify `Foo`, it exists in another codebase that I'm patching]

Comment: Please include the error that this gives.

Comment: @0x5453 doesn't produce an error, but it provides a bound-method object instead of the plain function object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose, you have:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @classmethod
...     def bar(cls, x):
...         return x*42
...
>>> Foo.bar(2)
84
```

Then one way is to access the name-space of your class directly. Then you should be able to access the `classmethod` object and obtain the decorated function available at the `__func__` attribute:

```
>>> vars(Foo)['bar']
<classmethod object at 0x103eec520>
>>> vars(Foo)['bar'].__func__
<function Foo.bar at 0x1043e49d0>
```

Alternatively, it is accessible on the bound-method object itself:

```
>>> bound = Foo.bar
>>> bound
<bound method Foo.bar of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
>>> bound.__func__
<function Foo.bar at 0x1043e49d0>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `__func__` attribute holds the wrapped method. Note that your wrapper will also need the `@classmethod` decorator in order to attach properly (otherwise it'll act as an instance method).

```
@classmethod
def wrapped_bar(cls, x):
    result = Foo.bar.__func__(cls, x)
    return result

Foo.bar = wrapped_bar
```